# How to filter MS Access field based on the value of another field

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I have an Access query which includes a field for [Month] and another field for [Fiscal_Year]. I would like to filter the Month field to only return [Month] 1 if [Fiscal_Year]= 2021, and return all [Month] if not Fiscal_Year 2021

Comment: This is really straightforward. You can use AND and OR in the WHERE clause of a query. Have you tried anything?

Comment: WHERE ([Month]=1 AND [Fiscal_Year]=2021) OR NOT [Fiscal_Year]=2021

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for the oops: replace null in filtered month with TheMonth to get the month)
A calculated field might be what you are looking for.  You can get more guidance on using calculated fields on the net like at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3

Assuming you are using the Access query designer Here is some sample data, a query, and the query results.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the detail on the calculated field FilteredMonth which didn't fit in the screen shot

```
FilteredMonth: IIf(Not ([table1].[FiscalYear]=2021) Or ([table1].[FiscalYear]=2021 And [table1].[TheMonth]=1),[table1].[TheMonth],Null)
```

Here is the resulting sql:
''''
SELECT Table1.TheMonth, Table1.FiscalYear, Table1.amount, IIf(Not ([table1].[FiscalYear]=2021) Or ([table1].[FiscalYear]=2021 And [table1].[TheMonth]=1),[table1].[TheMonth],Null) AS FilteredMonth
FROM Table1;
''''

IIF or "if and only if" is a built in access function which you can look up.